# WACounter is displayed but doesn't increase/decrease

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm new to smalltalk/pharo/seaside and i get trouble using a simple WACounter.
I created a component and added this:

```
wa := WACounter new.
html render: wa.
```

The counter is displayed in my localhost but doesn't increase/decrease on click. It must be silly but i can't find what's happend.
thanks

Comment: What version of Pharo and Seaside are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make the counter an instance variable, eg

```
counter
    ^ counter
```

and

```
counter: aCounter
    counter := aCounter.
```

then, your `#children` should answer this counter, too:

```
children
    ^ Array with: self counter
```

In your rendering method, then just render the counter:

```
renderContentOn: html

    html render: self counter.
```